# Using an Instangram gem in Rails. uninitialized constant Instagram error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, instagram

I install gem "Instagram" and write it in Gemfile. So, the `Using instagram 1.1.3` has been installed. Later I create in `config/initializers/` `instagram.rb` with:

```
require "instagram"

Instagram.configure do |config|
  config.client_id = "***"
  config.access_token = "***"
end
```

someController:

def index
    @instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media("alizade", {:count => 6})
  end

and in the `index.html.erb` wrote:

```
<% @instagram.each do |instagram| %>
    <%= image_tag instagram.images.standard_resolution.url %>
<% end %>
```

But it prints the next error:

```
uninitialized constant someController::Instagram
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use root module access from **someController**, and explicitly specify `require 'instagram'` in the controller in `development` mode, additinally to the same line in the initializer:

```
require 'instagram'

@instagram = ::Instagram.user_recent_media("alizade", {:count => 6})
```

Comment: and now just it `uninitialized constant Instagram` without `someController::Instagram`

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade that means that you have to use `require 'instagram'` explicitly in controller in development mode

Comment: But when I remove this line from `config/initializers/instagram.rb` it error stays

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade you should not remove the line from initializer